# How to remove an element previously added into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Could you please help me figure out how will I make it possible to create a delete command?
in selection 5. I must use **array** not `ArrayList` neither `Vector`?

**//Package ask1 main class Library**

```
 package ask1;


 import java.lang.Object.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.io.*;
public class library {



public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {



Management manager = new Management();
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    Book vivlio = new Book();

    System.out.println("\n\t\t^*^*^*^*^*^*^* LIBRARY  MANAGEMENT ^*^*^*^*^*^*^");

    while(true){
    System.out.println("------------------MENU-------------------------------"); 
System.out.print("\nENTER UR CHOICE\n\t1:Add a new Book\n\t2:Edit Book Infos\n\t3:Search a Book (with ISBN)\n\t4:Show all the Books\n\t5:Delete a Book (with ISBN)\n\t6:Exit \n   :");
int selection;
selection=input.nextInt();
 if (selection == 1)
 {

     System.out.println("Adding a new book ");
        String empty = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("name of book:");
        vivlio.name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Author:");
        vivlio.author = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("ISBN:");
        vivlio.isbn = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Number of copies:");
        vivlio.number = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");

        manager.AddBook(vivlio);

 }


 else
     if (selection == 2) {

            System.out.println("Editing a Book ");
            System.out.println("Please enter title of book to edit:");
            String title = input.next();
            Book editingBook = findBookByTitle(title);
            if(editingBook == null) {
                System.out.println("Sorry no book found with title name = " + title);
            } else {
                //ask user for new price etc what ever you want to edit.
                System.out.println("Please enter new values:");
                String newValue = input.nextLine();
                editingBook.setPrice(newValue);
                // etc. other editing to book.
            }
        }


        else
            if (selection == 3)
            {
                System.out.println("Searching a  Book ");


            }
            else
                if (selection == 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("You Choose to  view all       the Books  ");
                    manager.PrintAllBooks();


                }
                else
                    if (selection == 5)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You Choose to Delete a Book ");
                        String empty = input.nextLine();
                    }
                    else
                        if(selection == 6)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Library System Terminated!!! ");
                            String empty = input.nextLine();
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Wrong Choice");
                        }

    }
}

private static Book findBookByTitle(String title) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

***here is the second class called Book***

```
package ask1;

   import java.util.Scanner;





   public class Book {

Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );


      public String isbn;
      public String name;
      public String author;
      public int number;


    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }
    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }    

     String bookinfo = name + "    ," + author + "    ," + isbn;


    public void setPrice(String newPrice) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

}

***And the third class called Management***

```
   package ask1;

   import java.lang.reflect.Array;
  import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.Arrays;


    public class Management  {
public  Book[] books =new Book [60];
String Sisbn;
int current = 0;
Library lib = new Library ();
Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

  //Number 1


public void AddBook(Book vivlio)
{
    books[current]=vivlio;
    current++;
}

    //Number 2


public Book findBookByTitle(String title)
{

    Book searchBook = null;
    for (Book vivlio : books)
    {
        if(vivlio.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(title)) 
        {
            searchBook = vivlio;
            System.out.println("New name of book:");
            vivlio.setName(input.nextLine());
            System.out.println("New Author of book:");
            vivlio.setAuthor(input.nextLine());
            System.out.println("New isbn of book:");
            vivlio.setIsbn(input.nextLine());
            System.out.println("New number of copies of book:");
            vivlio.setNumber(input.nextInt());

       break; }
    }
    return searchBook;
}

public String getSisbn() {
    return Sisbn;
}

public void setSisbn(String sisbn) {
    Sisbn = sisbn;
}

public Book[] getBooks() {
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(Book[] books) {
    this.books = books;
}

public int getCurrent() {
    return current;
}

public void setCurrent(int current) {
    this.current = current;
}

//Number3




    public Book findBookByISBN(String isbn) 
    {
        Book searchBook = null;
        for (Book vivlio : books)
        {
            if(vivlio.getIsbn().equalsIgnoreCase(isbn)) 
            {
                searchBook = vivlio;
                String book = vivlio.getName();
                lib.once=vivlio.getName();
                System.out.println(lib.once);

                break;
            }
        }

        return searchBook;
    }




//Number 4
public void PrintAllBooks()
{
        for (int i=0;i<current;i++)
    {
            Book b = books[i];
            System.out.println(b.name);     
    }   
}

//number 5

  public Book DeleteWithIsbn(String isbn) 
    {
        Book searchBook = null;
        for (Book vivlio : books)
        {
            if(vivlio.getIsbn().equalsIgnoreCase(isbn)) 
            {

                searchBook = vivlio;
                books[current]=null;
                for (int i=0;i<current;current--)
                {
                    Book b = books[i];
                System.out.println(b.name);
                break;
            }
            }
        }

        return searchBook;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need to use array?

Comment: Because its an assignment from my college and it restricts us into using array exclusively

Comment: There is no actual deletion of an array element.You can make it null and then let GC do the actual work of cleaning it up.This is how it works in the ArrayList implementation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't attempt to 'delete' it still finds. Try the following instead:

(Untested but gives you the idea)

```
public boolean DeleteWithIsbn(String isbn) {
    int index = 0;
    for (Book vivlio : books) {
        if(vivlio.getIsbn().equalsIgnoreCase(isbn)) { //find the right book
            for (int i = index; i < books.length - 1; i++) {
                books[i] = books[i+1]; //move all the other books up
            }
            books[books.length -1] = null; //reset the last one in the array
            return true;
        }
        count++;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This method will return `false` if it cannot find the book. It returns `true` otherwise.

Of course this all assumes that the book only ever exists once in the array.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your indentation on your if/else statements, and consider using a case statement instead.

Second, your Selection 5 isn't actually deleting anything -- it's just setting String empty to the next line. Get the user-inputted ISBN with Scanner, and make sure to call Book.DeleteBookWithISBN(isbn) with that isbn. Then it'll do what you want :)